# Did the family of Osama Abu Essa, a Bedouin man killed by Hamas, offer a $1m reward for his killers?

Tags: israel-hamas-war, hamas

There's this story circulating on Reddit about a family of an Israeli Arab killed by Hamas on the 7th of October placing a bounty for information about his killers.

- Mako, an Israeli online news outlet, [reports (Google-translated from Hebrew)](https://www.mako.co.il/men-men_news/Article-0b32da4afb4ab81026.htm):

> The family of Osama Abu Essa from Tel Sheva is offering a reward of one million dollars to anyone who brings information about the terrorists who were recorded brutally abusing him before murdering him. Abu Asa's abuse was recorded by a car camera shortly before he was executed. His family member: "We will get to them even if it takes 50 years. Revenge will come and it will be cruel"

- [Alexander Nevzorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Nevzorov) [reported on Telegram (Google-translated from Russian)](https://t.me/nevzorovtv/11932):

> The Bedouin Abu-Asa clan living in the Negrev desert - (armed and very dangerous) put a price of one million dollars on the head of the Hamas terrorist who killed their relative Osama Abu-Asa on October 7, during the invasion of southern Israel.
> In the video these are the same Bedouins. According to their customs, they must find and kill the killers.

[Note one source claims a bounty for information about the killers, the other for killing them]

Are either of these true?

Comment: You need to link to it for notability purposes. Social media claims are [typically] judged in terms of views/votes here, whether they qualify as notable.

Comment: @Fizz it looks pretty brutal tho

Comment: Don't post images here. Put the link behind a warning, so people can choose to view them.

But I haven't found anyone saying this despite a brief search.

Comment: The story was published, so I assume we can even trace it to some Hebrew source. Here is a second hand claim in Russian: https://t.me/s/nevzorovtv?before=11928

Comment: Here is a claim in Hebrew: https://www.mako.co.il/men-men_news/Article-0b32da4afb4ab81026.htm

Comment: Is there a reason to think Mako is a disreputable source? Otherwise this Q rather answers itself. What would you want as confirmation? An interview with the family in another source?

Comment: @Fizz an international source? i am curious why no one interviewed them from the reputable international press?

Comment: Why would they? Calls for revenge don't make that good [of a] press in the West. And with thousands of potential stories related to the victims...

Comment: FWTW, there are sometimes Q here whether offered rewards are real https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50600/is-there-a-million-%e2%82%ac-reward-for-proof-of-sars-cov-2-isolation But you don't seem to ponder that, just whether they said it. And I'm not sure whether they'll pay is answerable.

Comment: @Fizz happened upon a reddit gossip, decided to fact check it, is all. it does check out.

Comment: It would have been better perhaps to put the t.me bit as claim and Mako as answer (even as self-answer). I'm still unsure exactly what was gory about reddit that you didn't link to it.

Comment: @Fizz if youre curious it was the capture of the victim by Hamas fighters, and one of the H. guys subsequently shooting himself in the foot, then they were doing what can be described as humanitarian violations with the hostage. in the comments were translations of the dialogue, discussions about the family of the victim placing a bounty on their heads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, his brother,  Joad Abu Asa, talks about the reward offer for information about the killers on a [recorded interview](https://www.ynetnews.com/magazine/article/sjwfjnomt#autoplay) with Ynet, an Israeli news site. Where he says that they can get the $1 million to even people in the Gaza Strip.

Comment: As it stands, this is a rather poor answer.  All we know is that "here" says it's true. Actual quotations and names of people or organizations would make it useful.